# How to create new shared project in TFS

Tags: asp.net

> **I created a new project , how can I add my local project to Team foundation server**.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181477.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a team project in Team Foundation Server

For more info

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181477.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to a TFS server in visual studio you should be able to right click on the project file and click
Add Solution to Source Control